# How to organize class interfaces hierarchy?

Tags: java, .net, frameworks

Since you can do multiple inheritance with class interfaces do you follow some concrete rules to create and organize them so as to avoid overlapping of interfaces for example ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you ask. Could you provide some examples?

Comment: And some example, please, where this *overlapping* is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule that I follow is [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns): every interface should model only one precise aspect or functionality, thus you can inherit multiple interfaces without having overlapping issues. You may want to read also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/separation-of-concerns), and related answers.

Comment: OK thanks I used to hear that AOP was needed to create Separation of concerns.

Comment: Citing [Wikipedia on AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) "In computing, aspect-oriented programming (AOP) is a programming paradigm which aims to increase modularity by allowing the separation of cross-cutting concerns". However, Separation of Concerns deals with the primary concerns of a class/interface, rather than cross-cutting concerns.

Answer (score 4):

Java (at least up to Java 7) does not support multiple implementation inheritance, only multiple interface inheritance. I guess you are referring to a situation like this one:

```
public class Overlapping {

    interface A {
        void myMethod();
    }

    interface B {
        void myMethod();
    }

    static class C implements A, B {
        public void myMethod() {
            System.err.println("it works!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new C().myMethod();
    }
}
```

This is not a problem (it works!). If API overlaps, it just merges.

[Here](http://java.sys-con.com/node/37748) is a useful article about multiple inheritance in Java.

Comment: the link to the article is broken

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about stuff like this:

```
interface I1 {
   void methodName ();
}

interface I2 {
   void methodName (); //same method name
}

public Class MyClass implements I1, I2 {...}
```

I don't know any concrete rules to for such situation, because they are very rare. (Not like in C#, there is a construct (explicit interface implementation) for this "use"-case).

In my humble opinion this case is and should be very very rare. Just try to avoid it (*/to hold it like this*). So it is more a academical, not praxis relevant problem.