# Can Class Interface be used for Separation of Concerns instead of AOP?

Tags: java, .net, aop

I asked a question about Interface here [How to organize class interfaces hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740780/how-to-organize-class-interfaces-hierarchy) and someone answered Separation of Concern.

Is there a link between this separation of concern with class interface and AOP ?

Answer (score 1):

AOP is just a different programming paradigm, which has OOP for a pillar beneath.

Class interfaces are something more specific and which should be used when you want to define a property that can be common between different classes.

The separation of concern that was mentioned probably is related with those different properties, which, when spotted and different, should allow for the creation of a new interface, consequently allowing other classes to implement them, and making it possible for them to have something in common that relates them and which is visible and explicit.

AOP shouldn't be used for that purpose, because it involves its own paradigm, and it is a task that you can already achieve with the interfaces. AOP changes things at another level, allowing you to change the behaviour of a whole program by defining pointcuts to be adviced.

Answer (score 1):

Using an interface you can group like methods together and then encapsulate the details in the implementation. This generally makes your application more portable. For instance if you have multiple DAO implementation for different database vendors, you can create an interface and implement it for each db. You can swap out the implementation while keeping the structure of the interface as the same.

Using AOP you can decouple the cross-cutting concerns in an application. For instance if all your DAO methods requires transaction management then that's a common concern and you can utilize AOP pattern there.

Separation of concern is a generic term and a common programming principle. You want to decouple as much as you can. Using both interfaces and AOP, you can promote decoupling.